# How can I check for Visual Studio updates via the command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, updates

In an attempt to streamline my Virtual Environment setup, I'm using [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) to automate my VM.

Since I can run the `cinst` command to install Visual Studio

```
c:\> cinst VisualStudio2012Professional
```

I'm wondering if after it's installed, is there a command line switch to check for (and subsequently "install") updates within Visual Studio?

Something along the lines of...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /InstallUpdates
```

This should also extend to any extensions that are installed along side VS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a way to check but it is not at all straight forward. Visual Studio Updates are published via an ATOM feed that is currently hosted here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=251032

This URL can be located in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Shell\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation.pkgdef

Under the [$RootKey$\ExtensionManager\Repositories{52943709-1abb-4abe-b413-41e8bb6d0462}] key.

The above URL should not change for any version of Visual studio BUT that is not a guarantee. If you examine the response of http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=290886, you will currently get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text"></title>
  <id>uuid:99B94631-1B1A-45A0-9C34-54F75988DD54;id=1</id>
  <updated>2013-02-12T20:00:00-07:00</updated>  
  <entry>
    <id>8EAF6C8E-1283-4EEE-AB6E-F0F087BFCBFF</id>
    <title type="text">Visual Studio 2012 Update 3</title>
    <summary type="text">Includes security updates, other critical updates, hotfixes, and feature packs that have been issued since the product was released.</summary>
    <published>2012-12-01T21:00:00-07:00</published>
    <updated>2012-12-01T21:00:00-07:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Microsoft Corp.</name>
    </author>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257044&amp;clcid=0x409"/>
    <link rel="releasenotes" type="text/html" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257045&amp;clcid=0x409"/>
    <link rel="update" type="text" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=302339"/>
    <!-- icon should be 32 x 32 pixels -->
    <link rel="icon" type="text" href="http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Content/VisualStudio/VSDownload_32x.png"/>
    <!-- preview image should be 200 x 200 pixels -->
    <link rel="previewimage" type="text" href="http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Content/VisualStudio/VSDownload_200x.png"/>
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
      <Id>8EAF6C8E-1283-4EEE-AB6E-F0F087BFCBFD</Id>
      <Version>11.0.60610.01</Version>
      <References />
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>28743233-1A36-4e67-8747-F072F8C76D1F</id>
    <title type="text">Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript</title>
    <summary type="text">This release updates the development resources for the controls, CSS styles, and helper functions that are included in the Windows Library for JavaScript.</summary>
    <published>2013-08-08T20:00:00-07:00</published>
    <updated>2013-08-08T20:00:00-07:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Microsoft Corp.</name>
    </author>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260891&amp;clcid=0x409"/>
    <link rel="releasenotes" type="text/html" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260892&amp;clcid=0x409"/>
    <link rel="update" type="text" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260893"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="text" href="http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Content/VisualStudio/VSDownload_32x.png"/>
    <link rel="previewimage" type="text" href="http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Content/VisualStudio/VSDownload_200x.png"/>
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
      <Id>Microsoft.WinJS</Id>
      <Version>1.0.9200.20789</Version>
      <References />
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Note that there are two entries in this feed and the one you are interested in is the one with a title beginning with "Visual Studio 2012 Update."

If the Version specified in this file (11.0.60610.01 here) is greater than the version you have on disk:

```
(Get-Item "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\common7\ide\devenv.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

Then you would want to download and install the url in the Link/@Update node:

```
<link rel="update" type="text" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=302339"/>
```

That Url should redirect to an MSI that has the update.

Comment: this is a good, but hacky way to solve the problem. Who/where would one send a feature request to include all of this in the devenv.exe command line switches? If it's one of those "never gunna happen" situations, I might just look at building an EXE to do just that, and pushing it to #Chocolatey.

Comment: Yeah. Probably not the API you were hoping for :) there is a uservoice site somewhere for submitting vs feature requests but I doubt it would lie high on the backlog. I too was thinking tlit would be cool to create a chocolate self-updater.while you can find choco packages for the updates. Its a pain both for the package producer and consumer to keep up.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information located in the [Devenv Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xee0c8y7.aspx) MSDN documentation. There is currently no way to call a command line swtich in order to check for / install updates to Visual Studio.

*however Matt Wrock shows a nice workaround in his answer.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Matt is outdated. For VS2019 follow this way:

1. Download file at https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel (it will be plain JSON file 'VisualStudio.16.Release.chman')
2. Check node: info->productDisplayVersion (or buildVersion) - they give enough info.

Comment: I've updated the tags to reflect that the question was asked re: visual studio 2012