# Redirect to my own website when press "Update" button in Visual Studio - Tools - Extensions and Updates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, updates, visual-studio-extensions

colleagues.

1. I created simple VS2015 Extension: myExtension.vsix
2. Then I created .msi installer (used **WIX** and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/873395/Installing-VSIX-package-via-WiX-installer))
3. It's OK! I installed my Extension and it works.
4. I created local private **MyLocalGallery.xml** and registered **myExtension.vsix** in it
5. As a result I see installed **myExtension** in *Tools - Extensions and Updates - Online - MyLocalGallery*
6. I increase version for **myExtension** in MyLocalGallery.xml => I saw my update and the button **UPDATE** here: *Tools - Extensions and Updates - Updates*

---

**QUESTION:**

I press **update**, VS takes

```
 <content type="application/octet-stream" src="Extensions\myExtension.vsix" />
```

from MyLocalGallery.xml and makes update. But... I want VS to make redirect to my own website where users can download **.msi** (not .vsix)

**How can I ask Visual Studio to go to my URL???**

If I remove this element

```
<content type="application/octet-stream" src="Extensions\myExtension.vsix" />
```

button **UPDATE** is present, I click it but nothing happens.

If I set .msi file, I get error (*"The file is not a valid VSIX package"*)

```
<content type="application/octet-stream" src="Extensions\myExtension.msi" />
```

May be it's very trivial issue, but I spent a lot of time trying to do it.

I can't find answer and hope you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer accidentally!

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555132/how-can-i-check-for-visual-studio-updates-via-the-command-line) helps me

So we should add element  to our entry in MyLocalGallery.xml:

```
 <entry>
    ...
    <title type="text">my extension</title>
    ...      
    <link rel="update" type="text" href="http://example.com/install.msi"/>      
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
     ...
    </Vsix>
```

And when we click Download or Update then VS redirect us to http://example.com/install.msi

Also we should remove this element from the feed xml (because it has higher priority)

```
<content type="application/octet-stream" src="Extensions\myExtension.msi" />
```